# EmberJs filterBy not returning results

Tags: ember.js

I'm struggling to get my head around a problem I am seeing and debugging is proving difficult.  See my code snippet below;

Worth noting that this is a slightly refactored version to make it more readable for developers who don't understand the domain in which I'm working...

```
 // snippet function from my controller
 availableChildren: Em.computed(function () {
    var adult = this.get('selectedAdult');
    var isMale = this.get('showOnlyBoys');
    if (adult === undefined || adult === null)
        return [];

    var children = adult.get('children');
    console.log(children); // returns Class {isFullfilled: false ...}
    console.log(children.length); // returns undefined
    console.log(children.get('length')); // returns 0
    console.log(Ember.isArray(children)); // returns true
    var childArray = Ember.makeArray(children);
    console.log(childArray); // returns Class {isFullfilled: false ...}
    console.log(childArray.get('length')); // returns 0
    console.log(isMale); // returns true, half the children are male
    var boys = childArray.filterBy('isMale', isMale);
    console.log(boys); // returns [_super: function, nextObject ...]
    console.log(boys.length); // returns 0
    // when this is bound to the Ember.Select it is populated with all 
    // the children of the selected parent
    return children;
    // if I comment out the line above and return the boys then the 
    // Ember.Select is not populated with anything
    return boys;
}).property('selectedAdult', 'showOnlyBoys'),

App.Parent = DS.Model.extend({
   name: DS.attr('string'),
   isMale: DS.attr('bool'),
   children: DS.hasMany('child', { async: true })
});

App.Child = DS.Model.extend({
   name: DS.attr('string'),
   isMale: DS.attr('bool'),
   parent: DS.belongsTo('parent', { async: true })
});

// in my html
{{view Ember.Select
    content=availableChildren
    optionLabelPath="content.name"
    optionValuePath="content.id"
    selection=selectedChild
    prompt="Please Select..."
}}
```

As you can see, I am trying to drive the items in a drop down list based on the results of another drop down list that populates the selectedAdult variable.  If I just return the unfiltered children of the selected parent then the dependant drop down list renders as you would expect, however if I try to filter the results the I get nothing in the drop down list.

I have tried various methods including Ember.RSVP.filter but I think that is silently failing because the children variable, as derived from adult.get('children'), is not a promise, its an Ember.Object.

The bit that I'm banging my head against a wall over is the Ember.isArray() that returns true, yet when I try to get the length (for debugging purposes), I always get zero.  Thought process was then, 'well maybe I have to cast to an array as its currently an Ember.Object' but that didn't work either.

Thoughts anybody?

Comment: I agree with GjK. The promise isnt resolving. Where are you fetching the models from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log(children); // returns Class {isFullfilled: false ...}
```

This means that your promise hasn't resolved yet, so there's no data. Ember-Data returns a [PromiseArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseArray.html), which is a promise, but implements array methods. So you can treat it like a normal array, but only after it's been resolved. Try adding `selectedAdult.children.@each` to the dependent keys for your property. The property will still compute before the promise resolves, but it should compute one final time when the promise resolves.

```
availableChildren: Em.computed(function () {
    var adult = this.get('selectedAdult');
    var isMale = this.get('showOnlyBoys');
    if (adult === undefined || adult === null)
        return [];

    var children = adult.get('children');
    return Ember.makeArray(children).filterBy('isMale', isMale).toArray();
}).property('selectedAdult.children.@each', 'showOnlyBoys'),
```

Comment: Ok so the get('children') returns a promise, which to be honest is what I thought, which is why I also tried Ember.RSVP.filter(children, function(child){ return child.isMale == isMale }). but it doesn't.  I found this but I can't see what I'm doing wrong https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1865

Comment: One other question, how would this allow me to filter the children before returning them? i.e. var boys = roundArray.filterBy('isMale', isMale);  I want to return the filtered results, I don't see how adding selectedAdult.children.@each against the property as a dependancy will work as the computed property has the dependancy on selectedAdult which is the variable that another Ember.Select control is bound... does this make sense?

Comment: I've never used `Em.RSVP.filter`, so I'm afraid that I can't give too much advice on that. But the reason that adding the extra dependency will help is that it will force the property to update again. The first time through, your filtering doesn't work because the PromiseArray is empty. If you add that extra property, it will force an update when the PromiseArray is populated, causing your filter to work as you expect.

Comment: Well I'm afraid that didn't work, I tried selectedAdult.children as well but both result in an " Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array." error.  Maybe time to try Angular, it shouldn't be this hard or painful to get cascading drop downs working with a bit of filtering thrown in.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not used to Ember-Data anymore. It returns a Set instead of an array, so you have to use `return boys.toArray();` instead. Also, Angular is definitely easier to get up and running, but don't make it seem like this problem is trivial. You want Ember to fetch data from your server and automatically update the page whenever something changes. That is not an easy problem to solve. (And going for the easier route of dirty checking, like Angular, is incredibly inefficient.)

Comment: yup that worked, included code in the answer to make this easy to follow for others.